# Command injection problem in controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, parameters, controller

so im having a problem with a security problem in my code.

Thing is, i wrote some code for placing a button in a form, so when you click it you check some things. So, i have my button which is calling a method called 'test_oid', which is in my controller. This method render a file with the same name and so on.

My problem is in the controller method. This method is called via ajax, and im passing some parameters via ajax to this controller, parameters that im accesing with params[:whatever]. Now, when i push this to my gitlab, i try to merge, its telling me about a vulnerability with some command injection in this method, and its obvious it is related to the params.

I know about the name_object_params, in which you allow which ones you want to use. This is my params method:

```
def monitor_category_params
    params.require(:monitor_category)
      .permit(:name, :description, :technology, :category, :main_category,
              :impact, :operation, :sensor_types, :default,:oid, :snmp_vars, :snmp_oper,
              :custom_tab_name, :custom_tab_unit, :redfish, :ipmi)
  end
```

But i think this params are used for creating and updating, when you click on the submit button from a form, the thing is that im still inside the form, i havent clicked the submit button yet.

Now, this is my method in the controller:

```
def test_oid
    oid_result = ''
    sensor_id = nil
    sensor_ip = params[:sensor_ip] || nil
    oid = params[:oid] || nil
    if number?(params[:sensor_id])
      sensor_id = params[:sensor_id]
    end
    community = Sensor.find(sensor_id).snmp_community if !sensor_id.nil?
    if oid and community and sensor_ip
      oid_result = `whatever`
    end
    if request.xhr?
      render json: {result: oid_result}, :layout => false
    end
  end
```

and this is the call to this method from ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/monitor/test_oid",
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {oid: valor, sensor_id: sensor_id, sensor_ip: sensor_ip}
     })
```

where im passing the variables that im using later with the params.

So, what is the problem here? The code works and all, but there is this security problem, in which i guess people can inject code with the params, but since the params im working with come from ajax, what is the problem? Thank you for the answers, im very new to this language and im still trying to understand the magic.

This the error that the test returns.

```
+SECURITY WARNINGS+

+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------->>
| Confidence | Class             | Method   | Warning Type      | Message     >>
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------->>
| High       | MonitorController | test_oid | Command Injection | Possible com>>
+------------+-------------------+----------+-------------------+------------->>
```

edit: as proposed, i used open3.capture2 instead of the backticks so now my code is like this:

```
def test_oid
    oid_result = ''
    sensor_id = nil
    sensor_ip = params[:sensor_ip] || nil
    oid = params[:oid] || nil
    if number?(params[:sensor_id])
      sensor_id = params[:sensor_id]
    end
    community = Sensor.find(sensor_id).snmp_community if !sensor_id.nil?
    if oid and community and sensor_ip
      # We use Open3.capture2 to skip a command injection security problem.
      oid_result = Open3.capture2('nice', '-n', '19', 'snmpbulkwalk', '-v', '2c', '-c', community, sensor_ip, oid)
      oid_result2 = `echo "#{oid_result.first}" | awk '/kB$/{ $(NF-1)= $(NF-1)*1024;} {print $0}'  | sed 's/ [A-Za-z]*$//' | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | paste -s -d';' -`
    end
    if request.xhr?
      render json: {result: oid_result2}, :layout => false
    end
  end
```

now the test are giving me 2 errors of command injection.

Comment: What is `\`whatever\`` really? The backticks run a shell and that shell will interpret what you give it, that would be your command injection. You're better off not involving a shell at all and using `Open3` from the standard library instead.

Comment: yeah my bad, i left an important part. whatever is a command that is using those params i was setting, so in this case i have:

`nice -n 19 snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c #{community} #{sensor_ip} #{oid} | awk '/kB$/{ $(NF-1)= $(NF-1)*1024;} {print $0}'  | sed 's/ [A-Za-z]*$//' | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | paste -s -d';' -`

Comment: The injection vulnerability comes from the string interpolation when building the big string that gets fed to the shell via the backpacks. All the `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, and `paste` stuff could be done in Ruby. Then maybe `Open3.capture2('nice', '-n', '19', 'snmpbulkwalk', '-v', '2c', -c', community, sensor_ip, oid)` to get the data. No shell, no injection.

Comment: sorry to bother again, i updated my question since this solution didnt work, or i did something wrong.

Comment: You could implement all the `awk`, `grep`, ... logic in Ruby rather than dealing with the shell and building a pipeline.

Comment: yes i thought about that, the thing is that the command injection problem now its also in the line with the Open3.capture2 and also in the next. If i delete those 2 lines, i dont have any problem. So the Open3.capture2 its not avoiding this command injection security problem i guess.